# How do you manipulate char* or char a[] via pointers from within a function?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

passing a char to a function I understand, kind of (and manipulating with pointers - below code swaps the value in c1 and c2).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
void swap(char* ,char* );
char c1 = 'a', c2 = 'b';

cout << "c1 = " << c1 << ", c2 = " << c2 << endl;
cout << "Now we swap."  << endl;
swap(&c1, &c2);
cout << "c1 = " << c1 << ", c2 = " << c2 << endl;

return 0;
}
void swap(char* a,char* b)
{char temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b= temp;}
```

but a string (where a string is an array of char declared char* a or char a[]) and then manipulating like with pointers I don't understand (below I would like to swap cs1 and cs2 but the code doesn't do it).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
void swap(char*[] ,char*[] );
char cs1[] = "Hello", cs2[] = "Goodbye";

cout << "cs1 = " << cs1 << ", cs2 = " << cs2 << endl;
cout << "Now we swap."  << endl;
swap(&cs1, &cs2);
cout << "cs1 = " << cs1 << ", c2 = " << cs2 << endl;

return 0;
}

void swap(char* a[],char* b[])
{char* temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b= temp;}
```

I would like to do it using these basic types instead of something from the String class.  I am just learning and would like to understand this before I move onto higher level stuff.  What is wrong with my understanding?

PS I am using g++

Comment: cs1 and cs2 have different sizes so swapping them wouldn't work anyway. If you use `std::swap` and `std::string` it is a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks to all and now I am one (small step) closer to understanding pointers (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers are indeed tricky, and to fully grasp them, it's important that you **read a lot** about them, in books, tutorials, etc..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(const char** , const char** );

int main(){

const char* cs1 = "Hello";
const char* cs2 = "Bye";

cout << "cs1 = " << cs1 << ", cs2 = " << cs2 << endl;
cout << "Now we swap."  << endl;
swap(&cs1, &cs2);
cout << "cs1 = " << cs1 << ", c2 = " << cs2 << endl;

return 0;
}

void swap(const char** a, const char** b)
{
   const char* temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b= temp;
}
```

In your code, you can't swap `cs1` and `cs2` as they are not really pointers. They are arrays, and how do you swap one array with another?

If you say `char hi[] = "TEST"`, the `hi` is the same as saying `&hi[0]`. It's address to first element.

In order to make the swap work, you need `pointer to string`.

Answer (score 0):

For arrays, you will have to copy the bytes in order to swap the contents of the array.

Pointers are just variables which hold the address.
When you try to swap two pointers, you are actually copying
one address into another.

Comment: _"Arrays are statically assigned memory regions."_ Huh?

Answer (score 0):

When you write

> ```
> char cs1[] = "Hello", cs2[] = "Goodbye";
> ```

you're implicitly declaring that `cs1` is a `char[6]`, an array of 6 characters. Schematically, it is [H, e, l, l, o, \0]. Likewise, `cs2` is a `char[8]`. These are different types! If you could swap the values of these two arrays, what should the new values be? Would `cs1` be a truncated version of `cs2`: [G, o, o, d, b] with no zero termination? Or should it be [G, o, o, d, \0]? Should `cs2` be zero-padded: [H, e, l, l, o, \0, \0, \0]? Or is it okay to leave the last two characters the way they were: [H, e, l, l, o, \0, e, \0]?

A solution is to declare `cs1` and `cs2` as pointers instead. In order to initialize them with string literals, they should be pointers to constant characters, `const char*`. See Chris Eelmaa's answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (and other languages where you have direct access to memory) there are multiple ways of "swapping variables".

When you write :

char cs1[] = "Hello";

then your program will allocate memory space containing "Hello" and have cs1 pointing to it, same thing with cs2.

cs1 contains the address in memory of "Hello".
cs2 contains the address in memory of "Goodbye".

Now you have at least three choices when "swapping". Do you want cs1 to point to the same address in memory but have that memory contain "Goodbye", or do you want cs1 to point to the memory address of cs2 ? Another possibility is to allocate entirely new memory for cs1 and cs2 and fill that memory with the string that you want.

Scenario 1 :
If you try to write the content of cs2 in the memory space of cs1, then you will run out of memory after 5 chars and will break the program, which is very bad.
cs1 points to "Goodb" and the memory cries

Scenario 2 :
temp points to cs1
cs1 points to "Goodbye"
cs2 points to temp

Scenario 3 : 
create new memory for temp1
write "Hello" to that memory
create new memory for temp2
write "Goodbye" to that memory
cs1 points to temp2
cs2 points to temp1

Your example with a single char is like Scenario 1, even if you use a temp.

a is a char*, so a points to the address of a, same for b.

```
char temp = *a; // This reads the value of the address of a to temp. To have the address pointed to use char* temp = a;
*a = *b; // The value pointed to by a is now the value pointed to by b  
*b= temp;  // The value pointed to by b is now the value of temp
```

You need to understand carefully why writing char temp = *a brings the value of a and NOT the address of a.

```
char* z = a;
*a = 5;
```

z is now 5 as well, since z points to the address of a and you changed that value.